# What would weather be like if the entire water on the surface of Earth freezes?

Tags: earth, weather, temperature

Earth is entering anther ice age and this time there will be no liquid water on the surface of the planet, the water cycle disappear as a result no Coriolis effect. What would the weather be like then? sunlight gets reflected off the ice sheet resulted in chiller day and freezing night, would the atmosphere become stagnant and homogeneous throughout?

Comment: A bit more specific, but related ;) http://what-if.xkcd.com/121/

Comment: The planet still rotates, so you still get motion in the air. It may well be less, but it won't become stagnant. Plus, you still have day-night-cycles, even if they are prpbably less pronounced.

Comment: @Burki: I was thinking without warm air rising from heated water body there won't be any pressure differences which produces wind, that's my argument but I aint no expert.

Comment: air will still be heated by the sun (although heated my sound a bit optimistic, it's temperature will still rise on the daylight half)

Comment: @Burki: oh I see you mean the land surface gets heated up so we get land breeze instead, nice!

Comment: "If a tree falls in a forest and nobody is there to hear it, does it still make a noise?" Such an event would leave no multicellular organisms on the earth's surface, so we'd essentially be Mars.

Comment: even if the whole surface is below freezing, ice will still sublimate, and direct sunlight will melt ice too. So there will still be water in the atmosphere. The Coriolis effect is about moving masses of air in a rotating frame. (earth) so is unaffected by temperature or water content.

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on climate here. But i think without clouds, ice reflecting a lot of sun rays from the ice layer, it would be very, very cold here. The earth still moves, so there would still be storms and wind, but no rain, hail, snow etc...

Without liquid water, according to what i know, no life can exist, and thus Co2 can no longer be converted to O2. The gas mixture of our atmosphere would change, and i am pretty sure the planet would no longer be able to support any kind of life form...

Not a happy future :)

Comment: The supply of oxygen would last a few hundred years before it contains too much co2, but since such a climate would kill off almost all life on earth, the oxygen supply would remain for tens or even hundreds of thousands of years for a small remaining human colony.  We could last even longer if we evolved or developed technology to remove co2 from our lungs.

Answer (score 1):

Our planet would be mars like planet(Mars transformed from a once habitable, Earth-like planet into the dry world we see today).
This is because of the following scientific research and detailed story.

Billions of years ago when the planets of our solar system was still young, Mars was a very different world.  Liquid water flowed in long rivers that emptied into lakes and shallow seas. A thick atmosphere blanketed the planet and kept it warm. In this cozy environment, living microbes might have found a home, starting Mars down the path toward becoming a second life-filled planet next door to our own.

But that's not how things turned out.

Today, Mars is bitter cold and desiccated. The planet's thin, wispy atmosphere provides scant cover for a surface marked by dry riverbeds and empty lakes. If Martian microbes still exist, they're probably eking out a meager existence somewhere beneath the dusty Martian soil.
What happened? This haunting question has long puzzled scientists. To find the answer, NASA is sent a new orbiter to Mars called MAVEN (Mars Atmosphere and Volatile Evolution).

The goal of MAVEN is to figure out what processes were responsible for those changes in Martian climate. **MAVEN** is bristling with instruments to study Mars’ upper atmosphere.  That's where many researchers believe the answer lies.

The only way Mars could have been wet and warm 4 billion years ago, is if it also had a thick atmosphere.  CO2 in the Martian atmosphere is a greenhouse gas, just as it is in our own atmosphere. A thick blanket of CO2 and other greenhouse gases would have provided the warmer temperatures and greater atmospheric pressure required to keep liquid water from freezing solid or boiling away.
Something caused Mars to lose that blanket.  One possibility is the solar wind.  Unlike Earth, Mars is not protected by a global magnetic field.  Instead, it has “magnetic umbrellas” scattered around the planet that shelter only part of the atmosphere. Erosion of exposed areas by solar wind might have slowly stripped the atmosphere away over billions of years. Recent measurements of isotopes in the Martian atmosphere by Mars rover Curiosity support this idea: light isotopes of hydrogen and argon are depleted compared to their heavier counterparts, suggesting that they have floated away into space.

Scientists have also speculated that the planet's surface might have absorbed the CO2 and locked it up in minerals such as carbonate. However, this theory has faded in recent years as Mars rovers and orbiters have failed to find enough carbonate to account for the missing gas.

**MAVEN** is the first mission to Mars specifically designed to help scientists understand the ongoing escape of CO2 and other gases into space. The probe  orbits Mars for at least one Earth-year. At the elliptical orbit's low point, MAVEN is 125 km above the surface; its high point takes more than 6000 km out into space. MAVEN's instruments will track ions and molecules in this broad cross-section of the Martian atmosphere, thoroughly documenting the flow of CO2 and other molecules into space for the first time.

Mars is losing CO2 right now, and it is extrapolate backward in time to estimate the total amount lost during the last four billion years. "MAVEN also determines if loss to space was the most important player in driving Martian climate change.

In the grand scheme of the Solar System, Earth orbits alongside a world that began with as much promise for life as our own … yet turned out so differently. After all these years, MAVEN could write the final chapter in a haunting planetary mystery.

**Therefore,I would conclude by saying that weather on planet earth would be close to what mars is today,basing on scientific research.**

And also,It would also have interesting effects on sea levels, sea life, and lots of other cases.

There are a few glitches in the plan though, firstly that a lot of Antarctica is already below the rightful temperatures. Secondly the state change of some of the ice would cool the other ice around it, slowing down the conversion. Essentially you have a negative feedback loop that will put the brakes on the process (although it would still continue).

The other is that you would get most of the cooling effects at the poles - which are already cold. The tropics would not be affected at all or until sea levels started rising. Ocean currents would be heavily disturbed by the sudden influx of fresh water at the poles though.

**That's it**

Answer (score 1):

The surface would be frozen, but ocean water would still be liquid due to the warmth of the planet, deepwater volcanoes, etc. You would have plenty of life in the oceans.

Water has a big heat capacity and ocean currents are a big source of heat advection on our planet (ex. Gulf Stream), so freezing the water would shut down those currents and even the temperatures. The variations in temperature would be caused by daily sunlight, from *very cold* in the day to *freaking cold* in the night.

At the surface, the low friction coefficient of ice would increase wind speeds all over the planet.

Answer (score 0):

## Impossible to tell

The thing that makes the question impossible to answer is that you have done **something** to the Earth's atmosphere. I do not know what you have done. But apparently it is something quite extreme since you have dropped the average surface temperature of the Earth by a whooping 25-30 degrees centigrade.

This is such an extreme change that it makes any predictions impossible.

Comment: Yes you may be right then could we can model based on other planets or moons?